# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't detect ssd

Tags: 14.04, ssd

I have a main disk, a traditional hard disk with ubuntu installed on it.

I bought a new ssd kingston drive, with 240 gb of capacity (SSDNow) and my ubuntu 14.04 it's not detecting it at all.

I already see it auto-detected on my bios, but when Ubuntu starts it's nowhere, i can only see my hdd.

I left some logs here that maybe have something to do with this problem (i never had an ssd drive before installed on my ubuntu, or in any other SO):

```
[94751.077217] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[94751.077226] ata4: hard resetting link
[94751.570882] ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[94751.570895] ata4: applying PMP SRST workaround and retrying
[94751.742592] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[94751.755197] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[94751.770215] ata4: EH complete
[104942.120941] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[104942.120948] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[104942.120953] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[104942.120957] ata4.00: failed command: SMART
[104942.120964] ata4.00: cmd b0/d0:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[104942.120964]          res 50/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[104942.120968] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[104942.120972] ata4: hard resetting link
[104942.613832] ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[104942.613840] ata4: applying PMP SRST workaround and retrying
[104942.785712] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[104942.798568] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[104942.813703] ata4: EH complete
[107340.003400] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[107340.003407] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[107340.003411] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[107340.003416] ata4.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[107340.003423] ata4.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 17 pio 512 in
[107340.003423]          res 50/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[107340.003426] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[107340.003431] ata4: hard resetting link
[107340.493518] ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[107340.493532] ata4: applying PMP SRST workaround and retrying
[107340.665384] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[107340.678416] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[107340.693387] ata4: EH complete
[107578.493916] systemd-hostnamed[10777]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[108909.824161] systemd-hostnamed[11062]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the gparted, create a partition and formated to ext4 and i started to use my disk. Without doing this i couldn't see it or use it in any way.